# Accessing identical web services using the same client

Tags: service, wsimport, qnames

I have some web services and I am creating a web client using ws-import.

When creating the client I have this line:

```
MyServiceService service = new MyServiceService();
```

It works fine as it is.

I have the same web service running on another server and I was wondering if I could access them using the same client. Is it possible to change the wsdl url of the client? Ctrl-Space in Eclipse gives me 2 parameters which I can enter into MyServiceService which are URL arg0 and Qname arg1. Is this what I'm looking for? And if this is the case what should I put in Qname since I didn't find any Javadoc associated and didn't find it on google neither

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. As you suspected, you need to use the constructor with [this signature](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#Service(java.net.URL,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName)) that is generated on your service class.
As you can see, it takes two arguments: a QName, and an Url.

The QName is a little bit tricky to determine. You have to look at the generated source code for the no-arg constructor of your service class (and the @Service attribute on the class). If you do this, you should be able to figure what QName the no-arg constructor uses. Just construct a QName with those same values, and use that.

The Url is easy: just use the wsdl url you want to access.

Comment: P.S. If you're still having trouble figuring out what QName to use, post the generated service stub source code, and I'll be able to show you what QName you need to use.

Comment: Brilliant! The QName is like this 
private final static QName MYSERVICESERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://MyService/", "MyServiceService");
Thanks a bunch! :)